# ListCtrlBox printing vba

Tags: vba, ui-automation

I've been trying to come up with a solution to print the content of a vba  control list box (including column name). As far as my research can tell, vba does not contain library with a print object the allows me to print ActiveX content. I imported the printerServer.dll that appears to come as an alternative from VB5 but it does not contain the properties and methods that comply with any logic I found on the web. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Dump the content on an Excel worksheet, print the worksheet?

Comment: Hey Mat, thanks for your reply! This is not in Excel but an automation controls software. Yet, I'd believe it uses the same libraries as Excel does since it is a VBa.

Comment: If you have Excel installed on that machine then you can add a reference to the Excel object model, create an instance of the `Application` class, add/create a `Workbook`, dump anything you want on a `Worksheet`, print it, and then close the workbook, destroy the application instance, all while your user doesn't even realize Excel is getting involved. "Tools > References" menu.

Comment: couldn't you just loop through the ListBox's items and print them one by one?

Comment: Mat's Mug, no excel installed on those machines. They are operator stations and are built to run Allen Bradley HMI operation only. I'm seeing the only way to print it will be through screen shot which is far away from what I needed but it is something. Thanks man!

Comment: E. Villiger, thanks for your reply! This is meant to be a report. Can't print one by one. Even the executeCommand "ScreenPrint" will give me a better output in this case. Thanks